# How do I add a new scope to a verified app without breaking our production website that uses the app

Tags: youtube-api

I have an existing app that is verified and the current publishing status is "In production".  I would like to add a new sensitive scope.

Is the only way to add a new scope is to change the publishing status back to "In testing"?

My concern is that by so doing, we will break production and new or existing users will have issues.

What is the best way to go about handling this (should we create a new app with the appropriate scopes and go through the verification process again)?

It seems the OAuth Consent screen options has changed.  I don't see any mention of scopes (existing or a way to add new scopes).  This app hasn't changed for several years, so it's been a while.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the only way to add the new scope is to change it back to testing add the new scope and then go though the verification process again.

unfortunately this will effect your users as they will see that your app is no longer verified.